# d3 - How to return d.type in v5?

Tags: d3.js

I have been using d.type in version 3.x, e.g.:

```
if ( d.type == 'unit' )
```

but this is not working in v5, where I get 'undefined'.  I had a look at the changes in v5, but cannot see any reference to d.type.

[https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md](https://jsfiddle.net/50e382oL/)

So, in the JSON for the d3 tree I have a 'type' field:

```
{"name":"MD","children":[{"name":"Professional","type":"theme","children":[{"name":"Professional Behavours","type":"strand","children":[{"name":"Year 1","children":[{"name":"Integrated Medical Sciences 1","type":"unit"},
```

I was using d.type to return the type for the node...e.g. `d.type == 'unit'`

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50e382oL/) of this working in d3 v3.5 where the type of the node is returned on right click of a node.

Comment: can you please post your entire code (working instance) ?

Comment: Try `d.data.type`

Comment: @Andrew Reid Thanks!  Do you want to put that into an answer?

Comment: Can do, will do so momentarily.

Comment: Just a small question, what about d.class, has that required a change in v5?

Comment: No sure if I follow on `d.class` - if it was a property on the original data, it should also be residing at `d.data.class` after passing it through d3-hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using d3-hierarchy each node in the source hierarchical data gains a number of properties relating to its position in the hierarchy. These properties include leaves, ancestors, etc.

When passing the result of d3-hierarchy to a layout generator such as d3.tree or d3.cluster, each node is further modified so that it has properties such as x and y to allow placement.

To avoid the potential for conflict in property names and to clearly delineate the data associated with any given node, the data associated with a node is placed into a new `data` property.

Consequently, if your  original data has a node property of `type`, once it is passed through d3-hierarchy, this property now resides at `data.type`. So in your example, you should be using `d.data.type`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var tree = d3.tree().size([100,100]);
   
var treeData = {
      "name": "Program", "type":"program",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Unit", "type":"unit",
      }]
    };
    
var root = d3.hierarchy(treeData);
    
svg.selectAll(null)
   .data(tree(root).descendants())
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.y+100; })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.x; })
   .attr("r",10)
   .on("click", function(d) { console.log(d.data.type); })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```